# Upgrading Swift app from heroku16 to heroku20 gives: "File format not recognized"

Tags: swift, heroku, vapor

I want to upgrade a Swift API (Vapor) from Heroku16 to Heroku20 with the "Upgrade" option in dashboard. Then I do `git push heroku master` from Heroku CLI. This generates following error. How can I fix this?

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Swift app detected
remote: -----> Using Swift 4.0 (from .swift-version file)
remote: -----> Installing clang 7.0.1
remote: xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Swift app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect Swift 4.0 isn't supported on the Heroku-20 stack. You either need to use an older stack or update your Swift version (and you should almost definitely update your Swift version because 4.0 is *old*)

Comment: @ 0xTim: the vapor buildpack has been updated by the maintainer but this didn't help. So I'm thinking of updating from Vapor 2.0 to 4.0, I assume that should work on Heroku-20.

Comment: Oh wow, Vapor 2 that's a blast from the past! Yes Vapor 4 definitely works on heroku